# Pass variable in tableview during segue IndexPath

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to take data from my tableview over to a view controller. So far I am able to move over the data that is being displayed in the cell but for some reason I can't take the variable with.

**Here is what is already working**

```
//Prepare for Segue
destination.titleSegue = (cell?.textLabel?.text!)!
destination.priceSegue = (cell?.detailTextLabel?.text!)!
destination.imageSegue = (cell?.imageView?.image!)!
```

All that data gets transferred over to the second view.

Now, I will show you my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle , reuseIdentifier: cellId)

    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() //Makes colour of cells clear so we can see the background
    cell.textLabel?.text = userList[indexPath.row].title //Shoes Name
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor() //Sets text colour to white
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "$\(userList[indexPath.row].price!)" //Displays price of shoes
    cell.detailTextLabel?.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor() //Sets text colour to white

 //LOOK HERE STACK OVERFLOW*******
 let descriptionText = userList[indexPath.row].description




    let URLString = self.userList[indexPath.row].listingImageURL //Finds URL of profile image

    let URL = NSURL(string:URLString!)! //Converts URL Stirng to NSURL

    cell.imageView?.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,100,100) //Sets frame size for images on tableview TODO

    cell.imageView?.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit //Sets image to aspect fill for image TODO

    cell.imageView?.hnk_setImageFromURL(URL) //Displays image on table view from Haneke Framework

    return cell
}
```

If you go back to my `prepare for segue` what would I need to call to parse the "descriptionText" variable from the `CellForRowAtIndexPath` to get the data to move over to the second view controller?

Comment: Where are you calling your `performSegue` code?

Comment: As always, **do not** get the data from the view (the cell), get it from the model (`userList`). Depending on the way to perform the segue (directly or via `didSelect...`) you need to get the index path in `prepareForSegue`,either via the cell in the `sender` parameter or via `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as @vadian said, in your prepareForSegue Method, you can get access to tableView selected row indexPath like this

```
let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow

let descriptionText = self.userList[indexPath.row].description
```